# how to manage the data in an xml file in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, file

I have written a simple wp7 application. i am using wcf service to interact with the database.  Now i want to store a part of user's info in the mobile also. this info needs to be accessible across the wp7 app.

I found multiple ways to do this like : isolated storage, resource files or static data in the app.xaml

Which one would be more suitable? as i may wish to edit the data in future...i may not opt for packaged files as they are read-only. also do not wish to lose data by storing in isolated storage.

Please suggest the most suitable option for me

Thanks in advance

Bindu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to store downloaded data between uses of the app. In this case Isolated Storage is probably your best bet. It will remain in the phone's non-volatile memory and you will not lose it.

Details [here](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/02/04/isolated-storage/)

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, but somewhere i have read that when we store some data into the isolated storage of the mobile, it will get destroyed or re-written in the file every time we launch the simulator! is it true? moreover i would like to store the data entered by the user into a form sort of a page which i have created as part of the application.

Comment: Isolated storage gets re-initiated ie cleared each time the emulator is closed but this does not happen on the phone. It is the only way to store data on the phone while your app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Resource files and static data in the app.xaml won't work for you since you want to be able to change these items at a later date since these will be read only.

I don't know what you are referring to when you say "lose data" by storing in IsolatedStorage.  This is your best bet and is actually really easy to do.  Here is an example of saving a simple boolean:

```
private void SaveSettings()
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    settings["VibrationOn"] = VibrationOn;
}
```

Then to load it later:

```
private void LoadSettings()
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    bool vo;  
    if (settings.TryGetValue<bool>("VibrationOn", out vo))
        VibrationOn = vo;
    else
        VibrationOn = true;
}
```

You would call your `LoadSettings()` method in the `Application_Launching` and `Application_Activated` events and then your `SaveSettings()` in the `Application_Deactivated` and `Application_Closing` events within your App.xaml.cs.

You can also serialize objects or write whole files.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. somewhere i have read that the isolated storage file will be stored in the title of the aplication and each time simulator is launched, the file will be re-written. so i mentioned to be "lose data using isolated storage". iwsh to know how far this is ture and any means to avoid such situations

Comment: @Bindu please see the comment from @SteveChadbourne. The clearing of isolatedstorage is only true on the simulator and only true when you close it (Not just rerun your app). On the phone, your data only gets deleted when either you do it or your app is uninstalled.  As for rewriting your file every time the app starts, that is up to your code.  You will want to verify the file doesn't exist before writing it, otherwise, yes you will be overwriting it.